# General form of the open mapping theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X,X_1,X_2,...$ be real valued random variables on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Let  $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.We know that by the open mapping theorem, if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ , then $f(X_n)$ also converges in distribution to $f(X)$. But my question is suppose $X_1,X_2,...$ are not defined on the same probability space i.e. $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, instead they are defined on different probability spaces say, $(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F_n},\mathbb{P_n})$  for $n=1,2,..$, and let $X$ be defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Then can we prove the open mapping theorem involving convergence in distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question whether $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X$ (or not) does not depend on underlying probability spaces but purely on the *distributions* of $X_n$ and $X$. That also explains why we speak of "convergence in distribution" in that situation.

Actually it should not be looked at as a convergence of random variables but as a convergence of probability distributions (i.e. probability measures).

The latter are off course often induced by random variables, but they can also be missed.

---

**edit** (a proof that leaves out random variables)

Let $P$ be a probability measure and let $(P_n)_n$ be a sequence of probability measures all defined on measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Further let it be that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int gdP_n=\int gdP\text{ for every continuous and bounded function   }g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$This actually states that $P_n$ [converges weakly to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) $P$ and the statement that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X$ is exactly the statement that the distribution of $X_n$ weakly converges to the distribution of $X$.

Evidently we have:$$g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\text{ is bounded and continuous}\implies g\circ f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\text{ is bounded and continuous}$$

Consequently for any bounded and continuous $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ we find:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int gd(P_nf^{-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int g\circ fdP_n=\int g\circ fdP=\int gdPf^{-1}$$where $Pf^{-1}$ denotes the probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ that is prescribed by: $$B\mapsto P(f^{-1}(B))$$

This shows that $P_nf^{-1}$ converges weakly to $Pf^{-1}$.

Comment: I have added a proof that leaves out underlying probability spaces.